# PreferenceFragmentCompat inside (child of) Fragment not dispatching first touch event

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

i am creating setting of my app and am using fragments i made `PreferenceFragmentCompat` screen and in my parent Fragment i load it on setting click but when i first click on any preference its does not respond to my first touch but after some short time it works normal or when i scroll up or down fast and click on any preference right after it it does not respond to my touch event can someone help please?

```
public class SettingsParent extends Fragment {

Toolbar toolbar;
private HomeActivity homeActivity;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    homeActivity = ((HomeActivity) getActivity());




    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_parent, container, false);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setTitle(getString(R.string.settings));

    setFragment(new SettingsFragment());

    homeActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            homeActivity.onBackPressed();

        }
    });

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("SettingTouch","parent");
            return true;
        }
    });

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = homeActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    return rootView;
}


private void setTitle(String string) {
    toolbar.setTitle(string);
}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.browser_options_menu, menu);

    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.grp, false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

void setFragment(Fragment newFragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.childF, newFragment, "detailFragment");

    ft.commit();
}
```

}

this is xml of parentFragment.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/child_fragment" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my child `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements HomeActivity.Authentication, Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, ConfirmAlertDialog.OnDialogClickInterface {
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {
    final String key = preference.getKey();

    switch (key) {
        case "remove_ads":
            homeActivity.purchaseRemoveAds();
            break;
        case "hide_icon":
            try {
                homeActivity.loadFragment(new HideOptiosTutorial(), getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "key_share_app_link":
            shareAppFile();

            break;

        case "move_to_sdcard":

            showMovetoSdDialog();

            break;
        case "button_internal":

            showMovetoInternalDialog();

            break;
        case "back_up_sdcard":
            if (isSDCardUnmounted()) {
                showSDCardMountError();
            } else {

                globalPasswords = getBackupPasswords();

                if (!FileUtilis.isSafAllowed(getActivity())) {
                    showSDCardNotAllowedDialog(983);
                    //
                    return false;
                }

                if (globalPasswords.size() == 0) {
                    showNoBackupFoundMsg();
                } else {
                    showDialogToBackupFromSDCard();
                }
            }
            break;
        case "change_password":
            showChangePinDialog();
            break;

        case "key_rate_us":
            rateApplication();
            break;
        case "app_link":
            SavedAlbumsFragment.showAppLockLink(getActivity());
            break;
        case "view_intruders":
            startActivity(new Intent(homeActivity, ViewIntruders.class));
            break;
        case "theme":
            showSelectTehmeDialog();
            break;

        case "enter_email":

            showChangeEmailDialog();
            break;
    }


    return false;
}
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers);
    Log.e("Mateen","onCreatePreferences");

    homeActivity = ((HomeActivity) getActivity());
    homeActivity.addAuthenticationListner(this);
    localDatabase = LocalDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
    localPreferences = new LocalPreferences(getActivity());

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(homeActivity).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("Remove_Is_Purchased"));

    removeAdsPref=findPreference("remove_ads");
    mCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("cat_remove_ads");



    if (localPreferences.IsRemovedAdsPurchased())
    {
        mCategory.removePreference(removeAdsPref);
        getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(mCategory);
    }
    else
    {
        removeAdsPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    findPreference("move_to_sdcard").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("view_intruders").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("button_internal").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("back_up_sdcard").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("change_password").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("key_rate_us").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("app_link").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("hide_icon").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("key_share_app_link").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("listPref_wrong_tries").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("theme").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("enter_email").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);




    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        findPreference("key_cam_short").setVisible(false);
        findPreference("key_vid_short").setVisible(false);
    }

    if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(homeActivity).getBoolean("key_intruder_detection",false))
    {
        findPreference("listPref_wrong_tries").setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (!Reprint.isHardwarePresent()) {
        findPreference("key_fingerprint").setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (!FileUtilis.isSdcardPresent(getActivity())) {
        findPreference("move_to_sdcard").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("button_internal").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("back_up_sdcard").setEnabled(false);

        //  findPreference("change_password").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("always_save_to_sdcard").setEnabled(false);
    }
    //add xml

}
```

but if i directly load child Fragment(`SettingsParent`) from my activity it works perfect without `action bar`.
can someone help or with better approach but i don't want to use activity i need fragment with action bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my problem by removing

```
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

from:

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

now it is listening to my every damn touch :D 
Happy coding